# getting error while creating Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am getting an error in my Mac's terminal while creating a new Angular project.

I wrote in the terminal

```
ng new ProjectName
```

**The error I got**

```
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"1.1.x","ncname":"1.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-08-29T03_03_13_191Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

**Full code  that I got after I run my cli command**

```
CREATE crud/README.md (1021 bytes)
CREATE crud/angular.json (3530 bytes)
CREATE crud/package.json (1308 bytes)
CREATE crud/tsconfig.json (384 bytes)
CREATE crud/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE crud/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE crud/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/environments/environment.ts (631 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/index.html (291 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/tsconfig.app.json (194 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/tsconfig.spec.json (282 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (987 bytes)
CREATE crud/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE crud/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE crud/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (300 bytes)
CREATE crud/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE crud/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"1.1.x","ncname":"1.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-08-29T03_03_13_191Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Try `sudo ng new ProjectName`

Comment: no , every time sudo does not help in terminal cli  we will have to use 
npm cache clean --force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

Should be solved after clearing npm cache.

```
npm cache clean --force.
```